# How to use jest.fn() on an individually imported function

Tags: redux, jestjs

I'm having trouble mocking the call of an individually imported function to my tests. The test is a simple function that I put within my Redux actions to be able to set a variable based on a condition.

Here's the function in Body.duck.js:

```
export const getCurrentOrPrevSelection = isExecutedFromPagination => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const {
    editor: { selection },
    body: { queryRequest },
  } = getState();

  if (isExecutedFromPagination && queryRequest.breadcrumb) {
    const {
      query: { branch, includeSplits, primaryFa, split, isInitial },
    } = queryRequest.breadcrumb;
    return {
      branch,
      includeSplits,
      primaryFa,
      split,
      isInitial,
    };
  }
  return selection;
};
```

And here's the test file:

```
import reudcer, { ...other exported functions, getCurrentOrPrevSelection } from '../Body.duck';

it ('should use selection in breadcrumb state when fetching new data from pagination action', () => {
    let isExecutedFromPagination = false;
    const bodyState = {
      ...initialState.body,
      queryRequest: {
        ...initialState.body.queryRequest,
        breadcrumb: {
          ...initialState.body.breadcrumb,
          query: {
            name: 'Full Book Performance',
            branch: null,
            includeSplits: true,
            primaryFa: 'AXFO',
            split: null,
            isInitial: true,
          },
        },
      },
    };
    const selection = {
      branch: null,
      includeSplits: true,
      primaryFa: 'AXFO',
      split: null,
      isInitial: true,
    };

    expect(getCurrentOrPrevSelection(isExecutedFromPagination)(jest.fn(), () => ({
      body: { ...bodyState },
      editor: { faidSelection },
    }))).toHaveReturnedWith({
      branch: null,
      includeSplits: true,
      primaryFa: 'AXFO',
      split: null,
      isInitial: true,
    });
  });
```

If I don't include any sort of mock reference to getCurrentOrPrevSelection, I get this error below, but it returns the correct value as expected:

```
    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveReturnedWith()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      object: {"branch": null, "includeSplits": true, "isInitial": true, "primaryFa": "AXFO", "split": null}
```

If I do something like `getCurrentOrPrevFaidSelection = jest.fn();`, I get an error saying `getCurrentOrPrevFaidSelection is read-only`

What can I do differently here?

Answer (score 0):

You want to test this function. So you don't need to mock that.

Just call function and verify result with [`expect().toEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#toequalvalue) or `expect().toMatchObject`.

```
expect(getCurrentOrPrevSelection(isExecutedFromPagination)(.....)).toMatchObject({
      branch: null,
      ...
    });
```

Also passing `jest.fn()` directly as argument does not really make sense: you cannot either verify it has been called or provide mock return.

```
const dispatchMock = jest.fn();
expect(getCurrentOrPrevSelection(isExecutedFromPagination)(dispatchMock, ....);
expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)
```

Once it's just not expected to be called as it is in your sample you better explicitly provide noop function `() => {}` instead of `jest.fn()`. This way you make it's explicit so nobody will be confused if it's expected there is no assertions against this function or not.

Offtop: actually this is not really good way to test redux action creators. See you actually test implementation details. What if you migrate from `redux-thunk` to `redux-saga` or `redux-loop`? Or split single action into 2 for better flexibility? By now it would mean you have to rewrite all your tests.

What if instead of testing action creator in isolation you connect action to real(not mocked) store? You could dispatch action(after mocking calls to external API) and validate store's state.